# If an antidote had a 96% success rate and you treat 100 patients. Does that mean 4 die?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

There are 100 patients and you treat each one of them with the same antidote. How many people will live? If the patient is not given an antidote it will mean a definite death. A success rate is defined as having the disease permanently removed with no other side effects. A perfect antidote.

Comment: No it doesn't. You are expecting that 96 will survive, but you may well cure all 100 of them (to be optimistic for the day...that rate would be 0.96^100)

Comment: Do you know the patients need the antidote to live?  There are many unstated assumptions in this question.  You are probably expected to assume that each patient does need the antidote and that survival is random with a probability of $0.96$ for each patient independently.

Comment: How is "success" defined? If the patient lives but is permanently impaired, does that count as a success?

Comment: If you repeat this experiment (100 people) over and over again then, on average, 4 will die.  But how many will die in each experiment varies.  It's pretty unlikely that all 100 would survive though (about a 1.5% chance) but there is about an 83% chance that [95 or more survived](https://www.google.com/webhp?q=.96%5E100+%2B+100+*+.96%5E99*.04+%2B+(100+choose+2)*.96%5E98*.045%5E2+%2B+(100+choose+3)+*+.96%5E97*.04%5E3+%2B+(100+choose+4)+*+.96%5E96*.04%5E4+%2B+(100+choose+5)*.96%5E95*.04%5E5).

Answer (score 0):

Until you wait and see the results of your treatment you can not make definitive statements such as "4 will die" you can only make statements about the probabilities of various outcomes, e.g. "the probability that *exactly* 4 will die is given by
$$P(X=4)={100\choose4}0.96^{96}\times0.04^4=0.199388...$$"

Comment: ...that _exactly_ $4$ will die.  I just want to make sure the OP understands the difference between _exactly_ $4$ and _at least_ $4$ or _at most_ $4$.

Comment: Good comment. Edited it in.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement means that you *expect* $4$ to die.

If you take a very large sample, as large as may be $10^{10}$, then you can say that $96%$ will live. For a small sample, the probabilities don't vary by a lot for $3$ dying or $4$ dying.

In other words, over the **long** run, for every $100$ people, $4$ will die.

Comment: In the **long run** we all are dead - "John Maynard Keynes" (1923)